# C# Text not appearing in a box (Unity 3D)

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Here is the script for my box, it is displaying the box but the text ("Press T") is not showing up. I have tried different dimensions of the box in case it was too small for the text to fit and it was ignoring the text, but changing the dimensions didn't change anything, I get no errors or warnings.

```
static float top = Screen.height * 5/6;
planeCanBeMade(){
     GUI.backgroundColor = Color.black;
     float leftside = Screen.width / 3;
     float rightside = leftside - Screen.width * 1 / 6;
     float height = top / 6;
     float width = rightside - leftside;
     GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
     GUI.Box (new Rect (leftside, top, width, height), "Press T");
}

void OnGUI(){
 planeCanBeMade();
}
```

Comment: Just curious if not using "new Rect" and just "Rect" works?

Comment: @orderof1 javascript allows just Rect but c# requires an explicit declaration of a new object before allowing it. When you leave off the "new" you will get the error that a behavior is missing.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Instead of updating the title to read "<Solved>", just choose your own answer.

Comment: @DuckMaestro It says I can do that in 2 days and I didn't want people to waste their time trying to solve this

Comment: @CodeMonkey then wait 2 days and remove the `<Solved>` from the title. If anyone waste their time, it's on them, not your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float rightside = leftside - Screen.width * 1 / 6;`
```

should be

```
 float rightside = leftside + Screen.width * 1 / 6;
```

or if I want to be really inefficient

```
 float width = Mathf.abs(rightside - leftside)
```

because when I take the width `right side - left side` it returns a negative value, which unity does not warn about when you draw a rectangle